# Changing C++ names convention automatically

Tags: c++, normalization, naming

My project is made of functions, classes, methods, etc. with heterogeneous names conventions. I concretely want to change all theses names from :

```
class MyClass
{
public: 
    void MyFirstMethode();
};
```

to

```
class my_class
{
public: 
    void my_method();
};
```

I am working with VisualStudio 2012, but can batch an external exe if needed, what I already do with AStyle for syntax normalization.

What tool could help to such a purpose ?

Many thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @leemes: I think he/she wants to automate it, which involves code analysis.

Comment: Yes sorry. The question is : what can I use to automate conversion ? tks

Comment: You can write your own  c++ code to do that

Comment: Sure, but I am sure there is already a tool (VS plugin or exe) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already has an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/635718/308182) using Sublime Text.

But you can do it yourself with sublime text.

- Open your src folder in sublime text
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to replace in files in the opened folder
- In the search option buttons by the left

  1. Activate regular expression search
  2. Activate case sensitive
- Part 1: Replace first letter of `CamelCase` with lowercase and prepend with underscore to give `_camel_case`.

  1. Find box `([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)`
  2. Replace box `_\l\1`
  3. Confirm your replace and wait
- Part 2: Remove first underscore of `_camel_case` to give `camel_case`.

  1. Find box `([^a-zA-z0-9])(_)(\w+)`
  2. Replace box `\1\3`
  3. Confirm your replace and wait

Comment: Using regex solution. Thx